# Asp.Net Identity check tokenlifespan time for two-factor

Tags: asp.net-identity, two-factor-authentication

I am trying for blocking multiple code sending for sms, until my tokenlifespan ends.Is there any way for getting tokenlifespan remaining time.

```
manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<FrUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity")
                )
                {
                        TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(SmsSettings.Settings.LifeSpan.ParseInt(3))
                };
```